# Wordpress | Convert #038; to &

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I need to pass a variable inside the permalink that takes me to my custom post, and then execute the `$_GET` of this variable inside an input of my cf7.

The only problem Wordpress encodes the `&` in `#038;`

I tried to decode the special characters but nothing.

Browsing the net, I found on another question here on stackoverflow, the possibility of using: `html_entity_decode`

But if I echo in frontend, it works perfectly, but when I click on the link it is converted back to: `#038;`

example:

```
<?php
$url = '?r='.$prezzo_finale.html_entity_decode('&#038;').'s='.$art_p;
echo $url;
?>
```

return me in frontend with echo: `?r=405&s=Sito Web`

but when i click on my post the permalink is: `/?r=405#038;s=Sito%20Web`

To pass the variable inside my post I use this structure:

```
<div class="card" id="professionista<?= $query->post->ID ?>" style="cursor: pointer;">

<!-- CODE -->

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("professionista<?= $query->post->ID ?>").setAttribute('onclick', 'location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink($query->post->ID).$url ); ?>"');
</script>
</div>
```

How can I get this converted?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because of the [wptexturize](https://wp-kama.com/function/wptexturize) filter,
Simply remove the filter or change its priority.
Note that this is a filter that deals with the security of the page and you should pay attention to exactly what you do to avoid XSS